# Why does my conditional formatting stop working when I use the format painter to copy from one Excel sheet to another?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, macros, conditional-formatting

I have a macro I created that has worked perfectly for a few months. It copies formatting and conditional formatting from one Excel sheet to another sheet that has raw data. The macro still runs but the conditional formatting stopped working correctly. I use Windows 10 Enterprise. The only thing I can think of is it stopped working due to an update. Is there a fix for this?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Are you able to share the VBA in your question?

Comment: **(A)** Only by looking at the Macro we can figure out what is going wrong , & then figure out what is the fix. **(B)** We would also have to look at the "Data" where is the "Condition" is failing to "format". **(C)** The Title says "Painter" but Post says "Macro" : Confusing !!

Comment: Do you use the code to copy the conditional formatting?